# socket.io-client via proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I need to run some socket.io clients via a socks5 proxy, I've searched here and there's a same question without any answers. 
NPM has some libraries/workarounds to support proxy connections but they're all http/https proxy based and none are socket based.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Are you running this clients in the browser or in node?

Comment: @DiegoRBaquero the clients run in node.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any implementation yet, you can take a look at https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-client to implement it yourself